# React: useEffect vs useMemo vs useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I was trying to find a concise answer to this on the web without luck.

Is the following correct regarding the differences between `useEffect`, `useMemo` and `useState`?

- **Both** `useState` and `useMemo` will remember a value across renders. The difference is that:

  - `useMemo` does not cause a re-render, while `useState` does
  - `useMemo` only runs when its dependencies (if any) have changed, while `setSomeState` (second array item returned by `useState`) does not have such a dependency array
- **Both** `useMemo` and `useEffect` only runs when their dependencies change (if any). The difference is that:

  - `useEffect` runs **after** a render happens, while `useMemo` runs **before**

Any other key differences I have missed?

Comment: did you read this? https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Your points are basically correct, some minor clarification:

**useState** is causing a re-render on the call of the setState method (second element in the array returned). It does not have any dependencies like useMemo or useEffect.

**useMemo** only recalculates a value if the elements in its dependency array change (if there are no dependencies - i.e. the array is empty, it will recalculate only once). If the array is left out, it will recalculate on every render. Calling the function does not cause a re-render. Also it runs **during** the render of the component and not before.

**useEffect** is called **after** each render, if elements in its dependency array have changed or the array is left out. If the array is empty, it will only be run once on the initial mount (and unmount if you return a cleanup function).

You can always check [Hooks API Reference](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html), which is a pretty solid documentation in my opinion

Comment: What I'm curious about is the underlying difference in declaring constants:

```ts
const foo = useMemo(factoryForCreatingConstant, []);
// vs
const [bar] = useState(factoryForCreatingConstant);
```

Both seem functionally equivalent.

Comment: You are right if you use it like this, they seem functionally equivalent. `useMemo` only recalculates if the dependency array changes which in this case it never does (since the array is empty). I have edited my post to take into account the difference between not passing the dependency array and passing an empty array. With `useState` you get a `setState` method as second array element though and can manually trigger a re-render, while useMemo would then only recalculate if its' dependencies have changed

Comment: FWIW, I was really curious about defining component initialized constants, which is why I added this comment. I ended up [posting a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57664450/usememo-vs-usestate-for-react-hooks-constants) on it if you're interested in the discussion.

Comment: @saltenhub I'm still unable to understand how `useMemo` is better, when it comes to heavy computation, than `useEffect` if both of them run only when dependencies change.

Comment: @NoamaanMulla `useMemo` and `useEffect` have different use-cases (the former runs during render, the latter after render - as explained above). In some cases, they produce a very similar/same result (see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/68201925/10320683)

Comment: One additional point of clarity, `useEffect` does not *always* run after render since, in cases when another render occurs too soon, the render is thrown away, and, for optimization, React skips the effects (since their intention is to post-manipulate the DOM).

Answer (score 12):

- The return value of `useEffect(callback, [dependency])` is `void` and It executes after `render()`.
- The return value of `useMemo(callback, [dependency])` is  NOT `void` but memoized value and It executes DURING `render()`.

`useEffect()` can give same optimization as of `useMemo()` under the following circumstances:

- The state variable used in the expensive computation (i.e., count1) is the only dependency of the useEffect.
- When we don't mind storing the expensively computed value in state variable.

```
const [count1, setCount1] = useState(0);
const [expensiveValue, setExpensiveValue] = useState(null);
useEffect(() => {
    console.log("I am performing expensive computation");
    setExpensiveValue(((count1 * 1000) % 12.4) * 51000 - 4000);
  }, [count1]);
```

- Only difference is, `useEffect()` makes the expensively computed value available after `render()` while `useMemo()` makes the value available during the `render()`.
- Most of the time it does not matter because if that value has been calculated for rendering in the UI, `useEffect()` and `useMemo()` both will make the value available before browser finishes painting.

Answer (score 2):

**`useMemo`** Used to memoize calculations/values that belong to the component but not necessarily to the component state e.g. validations, methods that rely on component and must return a value;

```
  const validEmail = React.useMemo(() => validateEmail(email), [email])
  /* Now use 'validEmail' variable across the component, 
     whereas 'useEffect' return value is void and only used for unmounting duties, 
     like unsubscribing from subscription e.g. removeInterval*/
```

[from docs:](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo)

> Remember that the function passed to useMemo runs during rendering. Don’t do anything there that you wouldn’t normally do while rendering. For example, side effects belong in useEffect, not useMemo.

---

**`useEffect`** [Side effects:](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect)

> Mutations, subscriptions, timers, logging, and
> other side effects

`setState`'s `setTimeout`'s `setInterval`' `ref` assignments, API calls, or anything that doesn't perform heavy calculations more belong in here.

Also remember that optimisation comes at a cost, therefore React suggests to use `useMemo` only when memoization/optimisation is necessary and in other cases rely on `useEffect` when necessary:

> **You may rely on useMemo as a performance optimization, not as a semantic guarantee.**
>
> In the future, React may choose to “forget” some previously memoized
> values and recalculate them on next render, e.g. to free memory for
> offscreen components. Write your code so that it still works without
> useMemo — and then add it to optimize performance.

---

**`[state, setState] = useState()`** [that is](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate) to update the given state variable which stays stable during re-renders and calling `setState` attached to it triggers a re-render. Purpose of this hook is not much relatable to the above two hooks.