# useMemo vs useState for React hooks constants

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Defining a calculated (initialized) constant using React hooks can be performed in two ways that seem functionally equivalent. I don't want to get into the use cases for this, but suffice to say that there are cases where a constant value can be derived from initial props or state that isn't expected to change (think route data, bound dispatch, etc).

First, `useState`

```
const [calculatedConstant] = useState(calculateConstantFactory);
```

Second, `useMemo`

```
const calculatedConstant = useMemo(calculateConstantFactory, []);
```

Both of these seem functionally equivalent, but without reading the source code, I'm not sure which is better in terms of performance or other considerations.

Has anyone done the leg work on this? Which would you use and why?

Also, I know some people will recoil at the assumption that state can be "considered constant". I'm not sure what to tell you there. But even without state, I may want to define a constant within a component that has no state at all, for example, creating a block of JSX that doesn't change.

I could define this outside of the component, but then it's consuming memory, even when the component in question is not instantiated anywhere in the app. To fix this, I would have to create a memoization function and then manually release the internal memoized state. That's an awful lot of hassle for something hooks give us for free.

Edit: Added examples of the approaches talked about in this discussion.
https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-platform-2b15l

Comment: What about using a [ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref)?

Comment: The point of the factory pattern here is that it only runs on the first render. After that, the factory doesn't get called. This allows the constant to be arbitrarily complex, but the logic only has to run once. Refs don't accept a factory like `useState` and `useMemo`

Comment: Maybe Im misunderstanding but I mean using a ref in the same way you are using here useState `const calculatedConstant = useRef(calculateConstantFactory);`. Just proposing a third option if it helps.

Comment: This would just be a ref to the factory in your example. Meaning: `calculatedConstant.current === calculateConstantFactory`. You'd still have to call the factory to get your value. In my examples the factory is called once and only once.

Comment: This is contrived, since the function is at least called to bind the name, but you get the idea. https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-platform-2b15l

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[You may rely on useMemo as a performance optimization, not as a semantic guarantee](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo)

Meaning, semantically `useMemo` is not the correct approach; you are using it for the wrong reason. So even though it works as intended now, you are using it incorrectly and it could lead to unpredictable behavior in the future.

`useState` is only the correct choice if you don't want your rendering to be blocked while the value is being computed.

If the value isn't needed in the first render of the component, you could use `useRef` and `useEffect` together:

```js
const calculatedConstant = useRef(null);

useEffect(() => {
  calculatedConstant.current = calculateConstantFactory()
}, [])

// use the value in calcaulatedConstant.current
```

This is the same as initializing an instance field in `componentDidMount`. And it doesn't block your layout / paint while the factory function is being run. Performance-wise, I doubt any benchmark would show a significant difference.

The problem is that after initializing the ref, the component won't update to reflect this value (which is the whole purpose of a ref).

If you absolutely need the value to be used on the component's first render, you can do this:

```js
const calculatedConstant = useRef(null);

if (!calculatedConstant.current) {
  calculatedConstant.current = calculateConstantFactory();
}
// use the value in calculatedConstant.current;
```

This one will block your component from rendering before the value is set up.

If you don't want rendering to be blocked, you need `useState` together with `useEffect`:

```js
const [calculated, setCalculated] = useState();

useEffect(() => {
  setCalculated(calculateConstantFactory())
}, [])

// use the value in calculated
```

Basically if you need the component to re-render itself: use state. If that's not necessary, use a ref.

Comment: This is a good answer. Thanks for the link to `useMemo` caveats. It also makes sense not to `useState` for something that isn't stateful. I can certainly build hooks out of the combination of `useRef` and `useEffect`. For your second example, I think you meant to put `if (!calculatedConstant.current)`. Thank you for your valuable input.

Comment: @bfricka Actually my apologies, there was one very important thing I forgot. You might need to use the second approach with the if, since otherwise the component won't update to reflect the initialized ref value (`calculatedConstant.current` would be null until the component updated for some other reason, like a prop or state change). I updated the response to reflect this, and fixed the check you mentioned.

Comment: Yeah, I already got there. Essentially I'm using two refs.

`export const useConstant = <T>(factory: () => T): T => {
  const initRef = useRef(false);
  const valueRef = useRef<T>();

  if (!initRef.current) {
    initRef.current = true;
    valueRef.current = factory();
  }

  return valueRef.current as T;
};`

Comment: I updated it again to explain how `useState` can actually have some valid uses here, depending on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: `function async` is backward; it should be `async function`. Also, you can't do `useState(calculateConstantFactory)` -- that just sets `calculated` to the Promise returned from the function, not the actual value it resolves with.

Comment: Great answer. Another factor is that `useMemo` is actually doing more than you need, i.e. memoizing. If you have one time initialization that's safe for a render method, `useState` is precisely what you want. If would be good if the hooks API reference called out this case.